# How to align Button in a custom ToolBar to Right

Tags: android, toolbar

I have made a custom ToolBar but recently decided to include a button on it as a home button. I have also defined it in java and it works when a button is clicked but the ToolBar title text shows half-way, i have tried to alignParentRight but it wouldn't work.
Please help me

Below are my codes and what i have tried.

**TIps_4.java Activity**

```
public class Tips_4 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    Button Tips3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the start page passed to us or default to first page
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int startPage = mIntent.getIntExtra("startPage", 0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tips_4);

        toolbar= findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        Button toolbar_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toolbarButton);
        toolbar_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent toolbarIntent = new Intent(Tips_4.this, MainActivity.class);
                toolbarIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                Tips_4.this.startActivity(toolbarIntent);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            }
        });



        ViewPager viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SimpleFragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this));
        // set the current page to the start page
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(startPage);

        //Attach the page change listener inside the activity
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(Tips_4.this, "Selected Maths Page:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetpixels) {

            }
            // Called when the scroll state changes:
            //SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });


        tabLayout= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }



}
```

**toolbar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:subtitleTextColor="#FF9800"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toolbarButton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ic_home_24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
        android:background="#000"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

**This is what i did that refused to work**

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/toolbarButton"
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#056359"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:padding="11dp"
            android:foreground="@drawable/ic_home_24dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**This is the screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete code for a toolbar with button at the end

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:subtitleTextColor="#FF9800"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mathematics Pages"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="right"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/toolbarButton"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:foreground="@drawable/ic_home_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="#000"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding   The button refused to move to end. What else should i do?

Comment: Also, how do i set padding automatically?

Comment: You must clear your cache and rebuild or clean your project because the answer is correct. I have been using this method for a long time. I am editing my answer and putting the complete code of toolbar and a button at the end!

Comment: Is there a way i can set the text programatically? I only know how to do that in ActionBar

Comment: Which text you want to set programatically? And is your current problem solved? If yes then mark my answer as correct!

Comment: I added TextView befroe the betton and it solved my problem

Comment: `toolbar.setTitle("your_title");` use this to set text in toolbar progamatically.

Comment: If you got the answer you should probably mark the answer as correct and close the question so that no one else makes effort to answer it. see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative layout and set its width and height to match_parent now add the button in you're relative layout and set alignParentEnd to true

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:subtitleTextColor="#FF9800"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/toolbarButton"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:foreground="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="#000"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

If you just want a icon in you're button you can use a ImageButton that works same as a normal button. And If you're icon is of fixed size say *24 X 24* then you can make the button as wrap_content in both width and height.

Comment: I iplementedthe solution you gave me but it refused to align to End.   See how i did it in the OP

Comment: Copy paste the code that I posted now. I tried in my app and it works. And if you want a icon in you're button then use imagebutton instead of button.

Comment: It has moved but i think there is an overlay. The ActionBar title text is not showing

Comment: I have posted the screenshot

Comment: You haven't added you're title in java code that you posted in your question